# Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) in Amazon EMR cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, infinite-recursion

We are running a Spark App on an Amazon EMR cluster. Our code takes in JSON data, converts it to dataframes, carries out Spark SQL transformations on them and then writes the resulting dataframes to csv files (at least, it tries to). However, when executing the code on an EMR cluster, we get the following error:

```
ERROR AsyncEventQueue: Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion 
(StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: 
scala.collection.convert.IterableWrapper[0]->org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlanInfo["children"]->scala.collection.convert.IterableWrapper[0]->
```

...etc

Can anyone help us?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you successfully run the code in other places?

Comment: Actually, yes, locally on our PCs

Comment: It’s stackoverflow error due to recursion. I doubt it worked in another environment.could you please change your code to use tail recursion so that it won’t create a different stack frame for each call

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight, we will try to use tail recursion :)

Comment: Code snippets are needed. To address this kind of problems